# Bugzilla - Email not working

Tags: perl, ubuntu, sendmail, bugzilla

I have installed Bugzilla-4.4 in my new Ubuntu Machine. When I submit a new bug, I got the email sent notification. But the sent email is not received by the recipients . I am using Sendmail mail configuration in Bugzilla. I have also tested "Test" mail configuration in which the mail is logged in `bugzilla-4.4/data/mailer.testfile` successfully. When I check my mail.log file I found the following:

> (1001/1001), delay=3+15:58:59, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=47643784, relay=mailrelay.netcon.in., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with mailrelay.netcon.in.

I have no idea what to do.Is anything I missed out while Sendmail configuration? Any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`nc`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) from command line:

```
nc mailrelay.netcon.in 25
```

which should result in something like:

```
220 mailrelay.netcon.in ESMTP Postfix
```

If not check for internet connection and/or router firewall rules.

Comment: Firewall blocked emails from my IP. I got rid of this issue. Thank you:)